# Auto-update iPhone content

Tags: iphone, synchronization

I am developing an enterprise app which has a lot of dynamic content. Is there a way to have the app auto update the content(new stories, download new videos, etc) at 3am every Sunday.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not have the app check for updates when it starts? Will the application be running 24/7?

Comment: App won't nessicairly(sp?) be up on the screen but would be running inthe background. There may be some large videos to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it’s not possible to do this when the app isn’t running, you can do it fairly easily at launch or while running (if it’s going to be running at 3 AM). Here’s what I’d do:

- Store an `NSDate` using `NSUserDefaults` for the last time you updated.
- At launch, if a 3 AM period has passed since that date, initiate a sync.
- Also at launch, start an `NSTimer` with a long interval—5 minutes or so. At each firing, check if a 3 AM period has passed and if it has, initiate a sync. You could even roll the last bullet’s code into this `NSTimer`’s firing method and just run it once at launch. Just be sure to update the `NSDate` object each time.
- In the application delegate, in the methods called from returning from the background, check the time and sync if necessary—or just start the `NSTimer` and have it fire immediately first.

That should cover all of the scenarios where you need to update the app.